# Like a post using facebook Sdk 3

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I retrieved all the posts from my Facebook wall but now I want to like the post using the `post_id`. I am using following code but getting below mentioned exception

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

My code:

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), fBPostId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() 
{
@Override
public void onCompleted(Response response) 
{
   Log.d("Like clicked",response.toString());

}
});
Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
```

Comment: Can you do a `Log` on `fBPostId` and check that it has a value in it?

Comment: Your code is seems ok. you can check session state is it opened? or check fbPostId is it right?

Comment: yes i m getting correct value in it

Comment: session state is open and post id is also correct

Comment: i m getting folowing in Session.getactivesession {Session state:OPENED,token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[friends_actions.news, read_stream, status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, email, create_note, share_item, publish_stream, read_insights, publish_actions, user_birthday, user_relationships, user_relationship_details, user_likes, user_groups, user_photos, user_status, user_subscriptions, friends_birthday, friends_relationships, friends_relationship_details, friends_location, friends_likes, friends_activities, friends_interests, friends_status, basic_info]}, }

Answer (score 0):

You should grant "publish_actions" permission to do that.

If you are using LoginButton :

```
loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```